# What is the city in Zootopia/Zootropolis called in the US version?

Tags: alternate-version, zootopia

In the U.K. the film Zootopia is called Zootropolis, possibly because of some copyright nonsense (http://www.irishtimes.com/blogs/screenwriter/2016/03/10/why-is-zootopia-called-zootropolis-here/). But I was just wondering if in the movie itself does the name of the city change between versions? In the U.K. version it's referred to as "Zootropolis" which could have been over dubbed, although the play Judy performs in at the beginning has "Zootropolis" written on a banner - possibly its written in other places as well - which would be harder to change. I also noticed that Gazelle opens her concert at the end with something like "Hello Zootopians" so my assumption is they missed over dubbing that line.

Follow up question; If in the US version the city is still called Zootropolis, why would they call the film Zootopia anyway?

Comment: They also inserted different scenes of different news casters in different regions. Changing a banner is nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the US version of the film, the city is called Zootopia.  As for why it was changed in the UK (and some other countries, apparently), [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2948356/faq?ref_=tt_faq_1#.2.1.3) has this to say:

> **Why is Zootopia called "Zootropolis" in some countries?**
>
> This was a creative decision made by Disney stating: "to merely allow the film to have a unique title that works for UK audiences." Despite not having any connection to any similar movies or TV shows with similar titles, **there is some speculation that it was to avoid confusion to an upcoming certain zoo in Denmark called "Zootopia"** as well where its owners have **had their trademark for the title since February 2010.** Director Byron Howard also answered the question of why so many different titles: "Licensing or trademark conflicts. All the same movie."

Comment: Yeah thanks. I'd already linked to info regarding the possible trademark dispute in the question so was aware of that.